# how to go to a page via seaschbox

Tags: jquery, search, autocomplete, search-box

I have a search box that, connected to my db, correctly finds the results needed by the jquery. My problem is:

the search button must go to the correct page. how can I do?

```
<style>
.ui-autocomplete-loading {
    background: white url("http://www.guiza.net/fotos/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/admin/css/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
    var cache = {};
    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            var term = request.term;
            if ( term in cache ) {
                response( cache[ term ] );
                return;
            }

            $.getJSON( "search.php", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
                cache[ term ] = data;
                response( data );
            });
        }
    });
} );
</script>

    <div class="inputCerca ui-widget">
        <input type="text" name="cerca" placeholder="A cosa vorresti giocare?" id="birds">
    </div>
    <div class="submitCerca">
        <input type="submit" value="GO!">
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that `search.php` returns a URL to which the page must be redirected? Can you show an example of the data returned?

Comment: The file search.php is autocomplete so it returns me values appropriate to the search. Example: I look for aa
Returns:
a
aa
aaa
aaaa

My problem is the next step.
I choose the value from the searchbox and I have to go to a page